# Redirect everything except a subfolder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this code in my .htaccess, but is not working as I want

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteOptions inherit

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old-domain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.old-domain\.com$

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog

RewriteRule ^/?$ "http://www.new-domain.com/" [R=301,L]
```

What I need is that everything that goes to **old-domain.com** [OR] **www.old-domain.com** goes to **new-domain.com** except the ***old-domain.com/blog*** folder. It's working quite well because is redirecting ok, but also my /blog is redirecting, and I don't want it to redirect to the new-domain.com

I have an alias domain in blog.old-domain.com and is working OK, but when I write ***old-domain.com/blog*** is redirecting to **new-domain.com**.

Any ideas?

-- EDIT --

I tried this solution, but still not working for me:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteOptions inherit

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old-domain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.old-domain\.com$

RewriteRule !^blog($|/) http\:\/\/new-domain.com\/%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works just fine for me.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?old-domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.new-domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Good solution! Works fine for me. Thanks!!